# Python script to click through drop-down menu and click a Download Data button

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I am trying to write a Python script that goes to a website (https://nammayatri.in/open/), clicks through each of the wards in the drop-down menu under Trip Trends ("All Areas", "Kempegowda Ward", ..., "Other Wards"), and clicks two buttons to download data for each of these wards (the buttons with the text "Download Data"). Note that the data downloaded changes each time a different ward is chosen.

The list of wards is not available in the HTML file, but rather appears each time I click the drop-down menu. Upon clicking a new ward from that menu, the HTML file changes in a way that also changes the updated data file that can be downloaded.

I don't really know where to start. Are there good tutorials or instructions to learn how to write this script? I would appreciate any references that could help.

Thank you!

Comment: Visit https://www.selenium.dev/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.